Calling Wintrust.WinVerifyTrust from Java via JNA returns error on signed .exe file
First time using JNA library and probably doing something wrong.
My goal is to verify an Authenticode signature of an executable file by calling the WinVerifyTrust function (from the Windows WinTrust library) in my Java code.
My solution below compiles and runs but returns -2146762749 as a result of the WinVerifyTrust function call. I'm running my test on the signed exe file and expect the result to be 0.
I've defined WinTrust library interface and used it. See the code snippets below
What am I doing wrong or how do I debug this issue? Any help is appreciated.
public interface WinTrust extends StdCallLibrary {

    WinTrust INSTANCE = Native.load("Wintrust", WinTrust.class, W32APIOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);

    GUID WINTRUST_ACTION_GENERIC_VERIFY_V2 = new GUID("{00AAC56B-CD44-11d0-8CC2-00C04FC295EE}");

    int WTD_UI_NONE = 2;
    int WTD_REVOKE_NONE = 0;
    int WTD_CHOICE_FILE = 1;
    int WTD_STATEACTION_VERIFY = 1;
    int WTD_STATEACTION_CLOSE = 2;
    int WTD_DISABLE_MD2_MD4 = 8192;
    int WTD_REVOCATION_CHECK_END_CERT = 32;
    int WTD_NO_IE4_CHAIN_FLAG = 2;
    int WTD_UICONTEXT_EXECUTE = 0;

    @Structure.FieldOrder({"cbStruct", "pcwszFilePath", "hFile", "pgKnownSubject"})
    class WINTRUST_FILE_INFO extends Structure {
        public int cbStruct = this.size();
        public Pointer pcwszFilePath;
        public IntByReference hFile = new IntByReference();
        public Pointer pgKnownSubject = null;

        @Override
        protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
            return Arrays.asList("cbStruct", "pcwszFilePath", "hFile", "pgKnownSubject");
        }
    }


    @Structure.FieldOrder({"cbStruct", "pPolicyCallbackData", "pSIPClientData", "dwUIChoice", "fdwRevocationChecks", "dwUnionChoice", "pFile", "dwStateAction", "hWVTStateData", "pwszURLReference", "dwProvFlags", "dwUIContext", "pSignatureSettings"})
    class WINTRUST_DATA extends Structure {
        public int cbStruct = this.size();
        public Pointer pPolicyCallbackData = null;
        public Pointer pSIPClientData = null;
        public int dwUIChoice = WTD_UI_NONE;
        public int fdwRevocationChecks = WTD_REVOKE_NONE;
        public int dwUnionChoice = WTD_CHOICE_FILE;
        public Pointer pFile = null;
        public int dwStateAction = WTD_STATEACTION_VERIFY;
        public Pointer hWVTStateData = null;
        public String pwszURLReference = null;
        public int dwProvFlags = WTD_DISABLE_MD2_MD4 | WTD_NO_IE4_CHAIN_FLAG | WTD_REVOCATION_CHECK_END_CERT;
        public int dwUIContext = WTD_UICONTEXT_EXECUTE;
        public Pointer pSignatureSettings = null;
    }

    int WinVerifyTrust(Pointer hwnd, GUID pgActionID, WINTRUST_DATA pWVTData);
}

WinTrust interface usage:
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String filePath = "C:/Installs/Installer.exe";
        Pointer filePathPointer = new Memory((long) (filePath.length() + 1) * Native.WCHAR_SIZE);
        filePathPointer.setWideString(0, filePath);

        WinTrust.WINTRUST_FILE_INFO fileInfo = new WinTrust.WINTRUST_FILE_INFO();
        fileInfo.pcwszFilePath = filePathPointer;

        WinTrust.WINTRUST_DATA trustData = new WinTrust.WINTRUST_DATA();
        trustData.pFile = fileInfo.getPointer();
        fileInfo.write();
        trustData.write();

        int result = WinTrust.INSTANCE.WinVerifyTrust(null, WinTrust.WINTRUST_ACTION_GENERIC_VERIFY_V2, trustData);

        // Cleanup
        trustData.dwStateAction = WinTrust.WTD_STATEACTION_CLOSE;
        WinTrust.INSTANCE.WinVerifyTrust(null, WinTrust.WINTRUST_ACTION_GENERIC_VERIFY_V2, trustData);

        if (result == 0) {
            System.out.println("The file is trusted.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("The file is not trusted. Error code: " + result);
        }
    }
}

